# Hard links break in Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, hardlink

I want to use hard links to avoid having to sync/copy a few source files between their base folders and a small git repo for personal development.

```
C:\PathLink>mklink /h test  C:\PathTarget\file.f90
Permanent link created for test <<===>> C:\PathTarget\file.f90

C:\PathLink>..\FindLinks\FindLinks.exe test

FindLinks v1.0 - Locate file hard links
Copyright (C) 2011 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

C:\PathLink\test
        Index:  0x0003F29B
        Links:  1

Linking file:
C:\PathTarget\file.f90
```

Everything looks good there, but when I modify and save the file using the "Target" access path (I just add append `fgh` to a line in Visual Studio) I see that the link is "lost":

```
C:\PathLink>..\FindLinks\FindLinks.exe test

FindLinks v1.0 - Locate file hard links
Copyright (C) 2011 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

C:\PathLink\test
        Index:  0x0003F29B
        Links:  0
```

After that, I can load the two files (`test` and `file`) separately, `file` reflects the modification, and `test` is the unsaved file.

Does anyone know why this happens? Is there a way to avoid it?

I *guess* I could initialize my repo in the PathTarget folder and then create an adapted `.gitignore`. There are already a lot of files in Target folder, and I just want to modify a couple of them. Moreover, I also want to add new source files and I find it less messy if I have my own folder, separated from Target folder. Hard links looked like it was best for me and I don't understand why it fails here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, the program you used to modify the file actually deletes it (breaking the hardlink) and then recreates it, leaving the original data in the file that you had hardlinked to it.

If you want a file to continue pointing at a different path/filename even if the target is deleted, you can use a symbolic link. Just use `mklink` in an administrative command prompt without the `/h` switch.

Comment: I thought symlinks would not point to files but to path, so that syncing symlinks in a git local repo would not actually sync files.

Comment: Interestingly enough, admin rights are needed to create symlinks so in the end I'm going to do the ugly fusion with an uglier `.gitignore` method